# java.lang.IllegalStateException: transaction is not active

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am doing batch update as shown below.

```
List<String> memberGuids = (List<String>) newMembers.stream().map(Member::getGuid).collect(Collectors.toList());        
Session session = super.getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
session.beginTransaction();
ScrollableResults members = session.getNamedQuery("Member.getMembersByGuid").setParameterList("memberGuids", memberGuids).setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

int count = 0;
while (members.next()) {
    Member member = (Member) members.get(0);
    updateMember(member, newMembers.get(count));
    if (++count % JDBC_BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

I am getting updated values in database but getting :

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active.

If I comment out the following code,

```
//session.beginTransaction();
//session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I get following error.

org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:548)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:900)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:789)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.progrexion.pfmetljobs.update.UpdateJob.updateMembers(UpdateJob.java:94)
    at com.progrexion.pfmetljobs.update.UpdateJob.job(UpdateJob.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:808)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:544)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.progrexion.pfmetljobs.update.UpdateJob.main(UpdateJob.java:56)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:103)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:544)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@bd93bc3 is closed
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.errorIfClosed(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:100)
    ... 51 more

Comment: You shouldn't be messing around with transactions yourself, let Spring manage those for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your comment. If I comment out the following code,
      //session.beginTransaction();
      //session.getTransaction().commit();

I get Caused by: org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@bd93bc3 is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I am using @Transactional on my function and using commit inside the function which transactional is doing already. So I commented out the following code and i worked.

```
//session.beginTransaction();
//session.getTransaction().commit();
//session.close();
```